# Access Sql Database in Visual Studio app, in Raspberry Pi

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, mono, database-connection

I'm creating in my PC a WinForm application that will run in a Raspberry Pi 3 with Mono.

I have an issue to get the path to a database (for the login form). Everything is working fine in Windows, but when running it from the Pi with Mono, I have some issues.

I already made a relative path, but I have an error message like "LocalDB can't be solved". Here is the Connection string I use (vb.net) :

```
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf" & ";Integrated Security=True"
        con.Open()
```

Do you know how could I solve the problem ?
(I don't know a lot about Sql, FYI..)

Comment: If you're using visual studio, you're not using vba.  Perhaps you should change the `VBA` tag to `vb.net` and you'll get better targeted help

Comment: Oh yes you're right ! My bad, I correct it. :)